# extract info from for each cicle outside $variable

Tags: php, forms, input, foreach

I want to thank all people aswered me. I edit my prev question.
Here you can find final result...

```
$newarry = array();
foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $selected){
echo"<input type='hidden' name='hola[]' value='".$selected."' />";
echo $selected."<br>";
$newarry[] = $selected;}

echo $hello=implode(",",$newarry);
echo"<input type='hidden' name='result' value='".$hello."' />";
```

If you call $hello (outside cicle), now i can see outside cicle {} all items.
Really good help, thx!!!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you allow people to choose multiple colors for 1 shirt but all you need is to add a name, brackets and some missing quotes

```
foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $selected) {
echo"<input type='hidden' name='colors[]'  value='".$selected."' />";
echo $selected."<br>";}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use IMPLODE like below,**

```
$newary = array();
foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $selected){
echo"<input type='hidden' name='colors[]' value='".$selected."' />";
echo $selected."<br>";

$newary[] = $selected;
} 

echo implode(",",$newary);
```